# Can I see questions with several tags?

Tags: support, tags, search

In Stack Overflow, posts/questions are arranged by tags. If I am interested in problems, I can find them by a tag.

But how can I find them by several tags?

For example, questions with `C#` and `ironpython`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Questions tagged C# and ironpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/C%23+ironpython) (88 questions)
- [Questions tagged C# or ironpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/C%23+or+ironpython)  (97331 questions)

The syntax is:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag1+tag2
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag1+or+tag2
```